# IOS GUI Hierarchie of a ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I dont know howto structure my view controller to match my following requests:

I have one screen which has 2 subscreens.

- 1. Screen shows an animation with pictures similar to a automated scrollview.
- 2. Screen shows some standard graphics (boxes triangles circles and text) depending on the picture actually showed in screen 1 (runtime interaction between the screens)
- I like to change the sizes of the screens at runtime, when a specific event occurs.
- I would like to have it as simple as possible :-) (of course)
- 1. Screen should be accessible from Screen 2 and other way regarding coding.

Howto structure this situation with todays Xcode and using swift ?
example Hierarchy:

```
ViewController
      Container with Viewcontroller, which holds my scrollview
      Container with Viewcontroller, which holds my custom view with graphics
```

or simplier:

```
ViewController which adds 2 subviews at runtime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `let UIView a` and call `self.view.addSubview(a)`. Then you can pack whatever you want in your view a. If you want to switch to the other view you can simply call `a.removeFromSuperview()` and add the other View.
Changing sizes would be no problem here, as you can just update `a.frame`.
For Accessing the other View you can just add a Button to your view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. This looks like a simple solution. I like to wait for probably other suggestions or upvotes on yours, but You will be a candidate to have the answer accepted :-) Thank you.